# Calculate numeric solution to equations

Tags: linear-algebra

If I know the following equations

$$ x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n = a_1 $$
$$ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 = a_2 $$
$$ x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \ldots + x_n^3 = a_3 $$

$$ \ldots $$
$$ x_1^m + x_2^m + \ldots + x_n^m = a_m $$

How can I get the numeric solution $x_1, x2, \ldots, x_n$ to the equations. $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m $ are complex numbers.

Is there a way to use a program to find the solution?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: i would solve this system for any special cases

Comment: The only special thing about this is that $a_m$ is equal to n, and there is no other guarantee about this equations